# ArcGIS Engine--load mxd file to map control or pagelayout control?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, mxd, mapcontrol

When I load an MXD file using ArcGIS engine, how do you automatically detect whether it's saved in mapcontrol or pagelayout control?

Answer (score 1):

Cast [`ActiveView`](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/componenthelp/esricarto/IMapDocument_ActiveView.htm) as [`IMap`](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IMap.htm) or [`IPageLayout`](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IPageLayout.htm) and see which sticks.